# how to go to central administration in SharePoint 2016 without logging to server

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, central-administration, url, farm-admin

Is there any way to go to central administration in SharePoint 2016 without logging to the server?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can by configuring the `Alternate Access Mapping` (AAM) for the Central Administration URL! in this case, you can browse the Central Administration URL from any PC within the network, but this will require providing the correct credentials to can access it.

**The required steps**

- Configure alternate access mapping via Central Administration.
- Configure SharePoint Site Bindings.
- Configure Hosts file.
- Disable loop Back Check.
- Add “A” record on DNS server for your Central Administration URL.

Check the detail steps at [Configuring alternate access mapping inside SharePoint server](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the Alternate Access Mappings would configured as :

Internal URL = the sharepoint url (with FQN)

Zone = Extranet

Public URL for Zone = the sharepoint url (with FQN)

Also add the site URL to trusted site .